# Manufacturing Process Validation - Sample size calculation

Tags: process, product-management, 6-sigma

I am new to manufacturing process. Can someone help me to determine the sample size required to perform Manufacturing Process Validation? I know nothing about six sigma, so simple answers are highly appreciated!

I believe what I need now is a formula, a description of parameters involved in that formula which I can easily relate to my requirement.

Comment: Your question missed information. You should include the requirements. E.g. in the medical device industry it is common to use a reliability + confidence pair. In addition, we need to know which kind of data you expect. E.g. if you are obtaining categorical data you have to use different methods then if you obtain numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

A sample size of 30 is usually sufficient if variation is VERY small, i.e. Cpk >> 2.00 ...but simple cookbook answers [from fora like these] are dangerous, especially for safety-critical component in things like automotive, aerospace, gas appliances or other things where failure can result in multiple deaths.

**Sample size is a matter of JUDGEMENT ... that means you have to use ALL of your available knowledge and experience, data on process variability and other information on different costs, risks and schedule impacts.**

First of all, consider what is the expected cost or likelihood of making an error of accepting a process when the process might not be capable, especially when Cpk is less than 1.5 and close to 1.33 (i.e. 1.33 is rejection territory and there is no reason to get more samples from a bad process).  Between 1.33 and 2.00 Cpk, you may want to increase sample to lower the risks [and possible large costs] of accepting an incapable process.

Next, look at the throughput on your measurement system, eg CMM(s) and personnel.  A large sample of 200 pcs might be justifiable for a buy off of an expensive tooling and inexpensive parts, but if you require 200 pieces for multiple part numbers across the board, you can quite easily cripple a new product launch with inspection for the sake of statistically powerful conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that nobody answered until now, I'll do my best by providing you the first google entry:

http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/sampling-data/how-determine-sample-size-determining-sample-size/

The page provides formula and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If by validate a process you mean show that it is able to meet tolerances consistently then you need to look at the process capability which can be done using the Cpk formula from the following site:

[Process Capability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_capability_index)

This tells you the frequency that your process will produce a part that is in tolerance.  You will need to determine a threshold for this value.
Some Cpk values with corresponding defective parts per million are:
1.0 Cpk = 2700ppm
1.33 Cpk = 63ppm
1.67 Cpk = 1ppm

A sample size of 30 is generally accepted as sufficient for this analysis.